# Understanding inserting by position with linked lists

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to understand inserting by position with linked lists in C. I found this code via http://www.cprogramming.com/snippets/source-code/singly-linked-list-insert-remove-add-count:

```
void addafter(int num, int loc)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp,*left,*right;
    right=head;
    for(i=1;i<loc;i++)
    {
    left=right;
    right=right->next;
    }
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    left->next=temp;
    left=temp;
    left->next=right;
    return;
}
```

It compiles and works just fine, however I do not understand this portion:

```
left->next=temp;
left=temp;
left->next=right;
```

If the next node pointer in left points to temp then wouldn't it get overwritten with left=temp? Could you rewrite this as:

```
left->next=temp;
temp->next=right
```

Can someone explain this to me please? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your alternative is as valid as the originals code.

Comment: So why use left=temp?

Comment: For that you have to ask the author, it's nothing anyone else could possibly answer. Myself I don't see any reason for it.

Comment: A pencil and a piece of paper may help here.

Comment: That code isn't very good in general. Don't use it as an example of how to write code.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition is same as it's posted in original code. 
It's value assigned to pointer (as temp, left, right are pointers), so list element is not overwritten by writing

```
left=temp;
```

but element under "temp" pointer will be available also under "left" pointer.

Personally, I agree with you that your code is easier to understand/read. It's all about writing code that matches real actions, not obfuscating it with additional variables or assignments.

Whatever, after you understand how linked list works, you can expect what function like this will do and any implementation is much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is equally right.
A even better one would be to eliminate the right pointer.

```
temp->next = left->next
left->next = temp
```

Note: You might want to change some of your code above